# Microsoft Botframework encode image bytes into message cards

Tags: botframework

I am using the Bot framework to create a chat bot. And I want to create message card (Hero or Thumbnail).

If you look at the skype bot api doc, there is a way to encode image bytes directly as the content url. https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/

```
"type": "message/image",
"attachments": [
    {
        "contentUrl": "<base64 encoded image>",
        "thumbnailUrl": "<base64 encoded thumbnail>",          // optional
        "filename": "bear.jpg"                                 // optional
    }
]
```

This works fine for showing an image only. But I want the image to be part of a card.

The card is

```
{
"type":"message/card.carousel",
"attachments":[
    {
    "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
    "content":{
        "images":[
        {
            "image":"https://foo.com/path/image.jpg",
        }
```

I have tried to set the image url property to the encoded bytes, but the client can't show it. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the basic idea.  Use this instead:

```
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "title": "Title",
        "subtitle": "SubTitle",
        "text": "Text",
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "image/jpeg;base64,{YOUR IMAGE}",
            "alt": "Alt Image Description"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks @Lars for helping. I tried to do this, but using the Bot Emulator 3.0.0.59, I don't see any image showing up.  

"attachmentLayout": "carousel", 
"attachments": [ { 
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero", 
"content": { 
"title": "Title", 
"subtitle": "SubTitle", 
"text": "Text", 
"images": [ { 
**"url": "image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYA.....**